# Jquery Mobile change Page not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i had a little Jquery Mobile site and i would like to change the page. The browser show the page and go back to index.

my target page:

```
        <div data-role="page" id="co" data-theme="a">
          <div data-role="header">

          <h1 id="contentTitel">Page Title1</h1>
          </div><!-- /header -->

          <div data-role="content">
            <div id="contentContent">COntene</div>
           </div><!-- /content -->

           <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer1</h4>
          </div><!-- /footer -->
       </div>
```

the "page change" function

```
function goToPage(target)
{
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#' + target, {
  transition: 'flow',
  reload    : true
 });
 }
```

what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: remove `reload`, it's useless since the target page is an internal page (hash) not a url. When do you call that function?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try out this code.

```
function goToPage(target)
{
  $.mobile.changePage("#"+target);
}
```